# HTTP Basic for API - How to "reduce" credential encryption?

Tags: security, http, encryption, basic-authentication

I currently wrote an API which uses HTTP Basic over TLS for authentication and I am quite happ y with it.

Now I bumped up the values for password encryption (like length, iterations, ...) to have a more realistic scenario. Unfortunately this made API access really slow as I have to rehash the HTTP Basic credentials over and over again.

**What would the easiest approach be (beside of sessions of course) to overcome this problem?**

Comment: Please explain "bumped up the values for password encryption" because HTTP Basic access authentication does not use encryption.

Comment: @MarcusAdams sure HTTP Basic does not use encryption but I have the user password stored as pbkdf2 hash in the database. So I need to hash the plain password in the authorization header and compare it with the one in the database. This takes some seconds when using really save hashing parameters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

pbkdf2 isn't meant to be called repeatedly, in fact, it's slow to prevent just that. This is generally combined with some session or token based authentication and SSL/TLS.

If your slowness is due to pbkdf2, and you don't want to do sessions or any similar token based authentication, then there's not much you can do here outside of abandoning or lowering the iterations for pbkdf2.

Though, you might consider abandoning HTTP Basic Auth, keep TLS though, and do your own authentication, then keep the connection open for additional requests. Of course, it's going to be up to the client to support this also.

Another solution would be to add more hardware to spread the load. Since the hashing is done on the web server and not the database server, you can add more web servers, web server CPUs, etc., and balance the load.

Comment: token based authentication would be oauth2-bearer for example or are there others available which might be simpler?

Comment: What about keeping a connection alive. How does this work? I mean I still would have to resend the header even the TCP socket is the same

Comment: @bodokaiser, I was suggesting something simple like PHP sessions though you could use any mechanism that trades authentication for a token (even oauth2 as you suggested). Take a look at [HTTP persistent connections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_persistent_connection) with `Connection: Keep-Alive`. You do send a full HTTP request each time, but there's no need to re-authenticate on each request since SSL/TLS prevents MitM attacks and you authenticate on the first request.

Comment: @bodokaiser, another idea ... more hardware. I updated my answer.